# How to write the limits under all three summation : $\sum \sum \sum_{0 \leq i < j <k\leq n} 1$

Tags: math-operators

I want to write the limits under all three summation means starting from summation left side going towards right side ( dependent limits) , Please help on this.

```
$$\sum \sum \sum_{0 \leq i < j <k \leq n } 1 }$$
```

thanks..

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. If you are using LaTeX, don't use `$$` for maths. Use `\[...\]`.

Comment: It is also correct to have a single $\sum$ even though three indices are involved.

Answer (score 4):

You can define you own math operator, `MySum` as defined below, or use `\mathop` and `\limits`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\MySum}{\sum \sum \sum}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|\MySum|
\[
    \MySum_{0 \leq i < j}
\]
or use \verb|\mathop|
\[
    \mathop{\sum \sum \sum}\limits_{0 \leq i < j}
\]
\end{document}
```